# I cannot install pdo_pgsql.so to use PostgreSQL in PHP

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, redhat

I have a site that use PostgreSQL database but I found that my RHEL 5 system lacks of pdo_pgsql.so file. I have spent several hours trying to install it but it was impossible.

When using "rpm -i" command with a lot RPMs found in Internet, I always got dependencies problems.

Last command I have issued before posting here was:

rpm -i http://yum.postgresql.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-5-i386/pgdg-redhat91-9.1-5.noarch.rpm

The output to that command was: package pgdg-redhat91-9.1-5 is already installed

And in fact, PostgreSQL database is up and running. The only missing file is pdo_pgsql.so.

I have used "find . / -name pdo_pgsql.so" to see if that file is somewhere in the disk, but without success.

Can you point me to the right direction, please?

These are relevant versions:

- psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.2
- PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Dec  8 2013 19:01:03)
- Server version: Apache/2.4.1 (Unix)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5 (Tikanga)

Cheers
Jaime

Comment: `yum install php-pgsql` (or the rpm equiv)

Comment: or `pecl install pdo_pgsql` + add pdo_pgsql.so to the extensions section in php.ini

Comment: You're using an extremely ancient operating system. Perhaps it's time to update from RHEL5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recompiled last PHP version with Postgres support option and the problem was solved. However, it is strange, because version of PHP I had before worked with postgres. For some reaon, it stopped working,